# using python pint how do I transfer a unit from one variable to another

Tags: python

In python, I do

```
from pint import UnitRegistry
unit = UnitRegistry()
a= 1*unit.m
b= 2
```

and I'd like b to have the same units as a. I know I can do

```
b=b*unit.m
```

but assume that a is the result of some long and complicated calculation and I can find it's units by

```
b.units
```

I'd like to do something like

```
b=b*a.units
```

I have found I can do

```
b=b*unit.parse_expression(str(a.units))
```

but is  there an easer way?

Answer (score 1):

To take the units from another quantity (`a`), you can do the following:

```
unit.Quantity(4.3232, a)
```